# Z-Index of element

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with an element overlapping another element that is a child of a sibling element. I have tried setting the z-index but I think because it is not on the same "level", it has no effect.

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/jw1mgrnz/1/

Is there any way to have the `class="sub"` element appear on top of the `id="span"` element without putting it inside the `id="box"` element?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jw1mgrnz/6/ like this you want?/

Comment: @Teoman-shipahi got it with http://jsfiddle.net/jw1mgrnz/18/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add

```
position: relative;
```

like;

```
.sub{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```